# problema de sql de funciones agregadas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Apenas estoy comenzando con SQL y estoy atorado en este problema. No se como puedo continuar. Es de funciones agregadas sobre un problema.

Tengo que escribir un query que me regrese el nombre de las personas que tienen menos de la mitad de dinero de la persona mas rica.

Las tablas con las que trabajo son las siguientes 
Tabla Estudiantes

```
| id | nombre      |  edad  | sexo
+----+-------------+--------+------
| 1 | Juan         |   23   | M
| 2 | Andrea       |   09   | F
| 3 | Abigail      |   27   | F
| 4 | Simon        |   21   | M
```

Tabla cuentas

```
| id |   Cantidad   |
+----+--------------+
| 1 |    2456       |
| 2 |    4632       |
| 3 |    17210      |
| 4 |    18131      |
```

Tabla CuentasDe

```
| id |IdCliente|idCuenta|
+----+-------------+--------+------
| 20 |    1       |   2     |
| 35 |    3       |   2     |
| 36 |    3       |   4     |
| 37 |    4       |   1     | 
| 35 |    4       |   3     |
```

Lo que he escrito hasta ahora no regresa nada y me siento un poco perdido. ¿Alguien tendrá sugerencias de qué podrá servir?

```
SELECT
  e.nombre
FROM ((estudiantes e
  INNER JOIN CuentasDe cd
    ON e.id = cd.IdCliente)
  INNER JOIN cuentas c
    ON cd.idCuenta = c.id)
GROUP BY cd.IdCliente
HAVING SUM(c.cantidad) < AVG(c.cantidad);
```

Comment: Puedes por favor agregar que has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias por ejemplo poner el query que te devuelve la persona mas rica? luego de eso, buscar las que tengan menos de ese valor... muestra algunos intentos alrededor de eso...

Comment: En que base de datos estas trabajando?

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si alguna de estas respuestas ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

La solución, en MySQL, a lo que estás buscando sería algo así:

```
SELECT nombre FROM (
    SELECT IdCliente id
      FROM cuentas JOIN CuentasDe 
      ON idCuenta=cuentas.id
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING SUM(cantidad)<(
        SELECT MAX(total)/2 mitad_del_mas_rico FROM (
          SELECT IdCliente,SUM(cantidad) total
            FROM cuentas JOIN CuentasDe 
            ON idCuenta=cuentas.id
            GROUP BY 1  
          ) c1  
      )  
  ) c2 JOIN estudiantes USING(id);
```

Dando como resultado:

> Juan

Que tiene 4.632, menos de la mitad de Abigail que tiene 22.763

La forma de llegar hasta ahí es en varios pasos:

Calcular el dinero que tiene cada uno:

```
SELECT IdCliente,SUM(cantidad) total
  FROM cuentas JOIN CuentasDe 
  ON idCuenta=cuentas.id
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Quedarte con el que más tiene y dividir esta cantidad entre dos:

```
SELECT MAX(total)/2 mitad_del_mas_rico
  FROM (
    SELECT IdCliente,SUM(cantidad) total
      FROM cuentas JOIN CuentasDe 
      ON idCuenta=cuentas.id
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1;
```

Identificar a los que tengan menos de esa cantidad:

```
SELECT IdCliente
  FROM cuentas JOIN CuentasDe 
  ON idCuenta=cuentas.id
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING SUM(cantidad)<(
    SELECT MAX(total)/2 mitad_del_mas_rico FROM (
      SELECT IdCliente,SUM(cantidad) total
        FROM cuentas JOIN CuentasDe 
        ON idCuenta=cuentas.id
        GROUP BY 1  
      ) c1  
  );
```

Y, finalmente, combinarlos con sus datos personales para obtener su nombre, que sería el último paso y la solución.

Todo esto lleva un montón de álgebra relacional detrás, no es trivial pero, con un poco de práctica, se puede llegar a obtener con relativa soltura.

Mi recomendación es que analices cada subconsulta, preguntes todo lo que no veas claro de cada una en los comentarios, intentes llegar a ellas tú mismo y, con la práctica, irás dando cada vez más pasos de forma autónoma. Ánimo con ello.

Adjunto dataset para las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE estudiantes(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31),
  edad float,
  sexo varchar(1)  
  );
INSERT INTO estudiantes (id,nombre, edad, sexo) VALUES
  (1,'Juan',23,'M'),
  (2,'Andrea',9,'F'),
  (3,'Abigail',27,'F'),
  (4,'Simon',21,'M');
CREATE TABLE cuentas(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cantidad float
  );
INSERT INTO cuentas (id, cantidad) VALUES
  (1,2456),
  (2,4632),
  (3,17210),
  (4,18131);
CREATE TABLE CuentasDe(
  id int,
  IdCliente int,
  idCuenta int
  );
INSERT INTO CuentasDe (id, IdCliente, idCuenta) VALUES
  (20,1,2),
  (35,3,2),
  (36,3,4),
  (37,4,1),
  (35,4,3);
```

Comment: Siempre siempre preguntar para que base de datos es!!!!

Answer (score 1):

me pareció interesante el ejercicio:

te dejo la solución en MySql:

**PRIMERO LOS SCRIPT PARA CREAR LOS INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`Estudiantes`(`id`,`nombre`,`sexo`,`edad`) VALUES(1,'juan','m',23);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`Estudiantes`(`id`,`nombre`,`sexo`,`edad`)VALUES(2,'andrea','f',9);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`Estudiantes`(`id`,`nombre`,`sexo`,`edad`)VALUES(3,'abigail','f',27);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`Estudiantes`(`id`,`nombre`,`sexo`,`edad`)VALUES(4,'simon','m',21);


INSERT INTO `prueba`.`Cuentas` (`id`,`cantidad`) VALUES (1,2456);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`Cuentas` (`id`,`cantidad`) VALUES(2,4632);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`Cuentas` (`id`,`cantidad`) VALUES(3,17210);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`Cuentas` (`id`,`cantidad`) VALUES(4,18131);

INSERT INTO `prueba`.`CuentasDe` (`id`,`idcliente`,`idcuenta`) VALUES (20,1,2);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`CuentasDe` (`id`,`idcliente`,`idcuenta`) VALUES (35,3,2);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`CuentasDe` (`id`,`idcliente`,`idcuenta`) VALUES (36,3,4);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`CuentasDe` (`id`,`idcliente`,`idcuenta`) VALUES (37,4,1);
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`CuentasDe` (`id`,`idcliente`,`idcuenta`) VALUES (35,4,3);
```

Y LA SOLUCION SERIA ALGO ASI:

```
SELECT 
    est.nombre,
    SUM(cta.Cantidad) AS Total
FROM 
    `prueba`.`Estudiantes` AS est
     INNER JOIN  `prueba`.`CuentasDe` AS ctaDe ON est.id= ctaDe.idcliente
     INNER JOIN  `prueba`.`Cuentas` AS cta on ctaDe.idcuenta= cta.id
GROUP BY 
    est.nombre
HAVING 
    SUM(cta.Cantidad) > (SELECT 
                            (SUM(cta2.Cantidad)/2) AS mayorDinero
                          FROM 
                            `prueba`.`Estudiantes` AS est2
                            INNER JOIN  `prueba`.`CuentasDe` AS ctaDe2 ON est2.id= ctaDe2.idcliente
                            INNER JOIN  `prueba`.`Cuentas` AS cta2 on ctaDe2.idcuenta= cta2.id
                            GROUP BY est2.nombre
                            ORDER BY mayorDinero DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                        )
```

**EXPLICACION**
Necesitas el nombre de las personas que tienen menos de la mitad de dinero de la persona mas rica, por lo tanto lo primero que debes saber es cual es la mitad del dinero de la persona mas rica(en este caso abigail con 22763) y es lo que usas en el select que va en el having.

luego debes sumar las cuentas de cada estudiante y compararla con la consulta anterior.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Siempre siempre preguntar para que base de datos es!!!!